# Can I give a public github action access to a file without placing that file in the public repository?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a public repository which updates every day using a github action. The update retrieves the latest version of a public dataset (call it Dataset A), then performs various transformations before updating a website.

I also have a private dataset, Dataset B, with some information related to Dataset A. In a single script, I can merge the two datasets, then calculate summary statistics from B, based on the current version of A.

I don’t want to share Dataset B publicly, because it has some sensitive information. I do want to share the summary statistics from Dataset B publicly in the repository that processes Dataset A.

As I mentioned, the repository uses a Github action to grab the newest version of Dataset A each day. The summary statistics from Dataset B need to be updated as part of the same automated daily process.

The repository needs to remain public. I’m trying to think of a way to give my workflow access to Dataset B without adding it to the public repository.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You'd put the credentials for the private data in a [Github Secret in the public repo](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions#creating-secrets-for-a-repository) and [have the action use that secret](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions#using-secrets-in-a-workflow).